# loss of the bookmark box on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, bookmarks

I am new to phpmyadmin and after installing and importing my databases at the beginning I could see where to save the bookmarks, but it disappeared and now I can't bring it back; I have already followed the instructions on this link https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/sql/create_tables.sql

and also looked at phpMyAdmin configuration storage but without success; please help me; I want to be able to see the box where to put the bookmarks to save them

[image sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1U77.png)

Answer (score 0):

Select Server:127.0.0.1 on the top of the page. Next, select the tab SQL and type

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'pma'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Execute query. This should fix the problem.